# Class Slider android

Tags: android, slider

I made this class , that extends from LinearLayout . It help me to appear or to hide some component when I press a button.
I had this error:"there's no default constructor in android.widget.RelativeLayout;" even if I made a default constructor.

```
 public class Slider extends LinearLayout {

     private Boolean isOpen;
     private RelativeLayout toHide;
     private static int SPEED;


     public boolean toggle() {
        TranslateAnimation animation = null;
        isOpen = !isOpen;

        if (isOpen)
        {
            animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, -toHide.getHeight(), 0.0f);
            animation.setAnimationListener(openListener);

        } else
        {
            animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, - toHide.getHeight());
            animation.setAnimationListener(closeListener);

        }

        animation.setDuration(SPEED);
        animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        startAnimation(animation);

        return isOpen;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error is actually telling you is that since the class you are extending (`LinearLayout`) doesn't have a no-arg constructor, your class needs to explicitly declare a constructor so it can call one of the `super()` constructors that has arguments.

For views usually the first argument is a `Context` object, so if you add a constructor like this the error will go away:

```
public Slider(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

Comment: I had this error :" cannot resolve symbol 'Content'.